# tmux の Window タブで ! が表示される条件は？

Tags: tmux

tmux を利用していると、今現在表示していない window の中で、プログラムが異常終了したときなどに、その Window のタブが ! になって、通知される場合がある気がしています。気がしています、というのは、たしかに何かしらの異常状態のときに ! が表示されるのは覚えているのですが、どのような条件でこれが起きるのかがわかっていないです。(例えば、sleep して異常終了するだけの shell script を実行してみても、 ! は表示されませんでした。)

tmux の、今現在フォーカスしていない window タブが ! を表示するのは、いったいどのようなときですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tmux(1)(`man tmux` したら出てくるやつ)のSTATUS LINEのところに

```
!         A bell has occurred in the window.
```

と書いてありますね。

Comment: `sleep 5; echo -ne '\007'` で ! を再現できました。